# Text Wrapping or auto width adjustment in Excel column using ColdFusion

Tags: database, excel, coldfusion, export, word-wrap

I am pulling data from a database and presenting it in Excel for the customer. The only problem is some of the data is too big for the column, and since the data is dynamic (of course) I basically need to be able to either do some text wrapping or have the width of the columns expand as necesarry.

My code is posted below

```
<!---Used for streaming to browser--->
<cfset context = getPageContext()>
<cfset context.setFlushOutput(false)>
<cfset response = context.getResponse().getResponse()>
<cfset out = response.getOutputStream()>
<cfset response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")>
<cfset response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ERD_Report.xls" )>

<!---Create Workbook and Sheets in workbook--->
<cfset wb = createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook").init()/>
<cfset sheet1 = wb.createSheet("ERD Report")/>

<!---Formatting--->
<cfset cellStyleStatic = createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle")/>
<cfset cellHSSFFont = createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont")/>

<!---Title--->
<cfset fontTitle = wb.createFont()/>
<cfset fontTitle.setFontName("Calibri") />
<cfset fontTitle.setFontHeightInPoints(javacast("int",11))/> 
<cfset styleTitle = wb.createCellStyle()/>
<cfset styleTitle.setfont(fontTitle)/>
<cfset styleTitle.setFillPattern(styleTitle.SOLID_FOREGROUND)/>
<cfset styleTitle.setFillForegroundColor(createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$GREY_25_PERCENT").getIndex())/>
<cfset styleTitle.setBorderBottom(styleTitle.BORDER_THIN)/>
<cfset styleTitle.setBorderLeft(styleTitle.BORDER_THIN)/>
<cfset styleTitle.setBorderRight(styleTitle.BORDER_THIN)/>
<cfset styleTitle.setBorderTop(styleTitle.BORDER_THIN)/>

<!---Regular centered white cell with Borders--->
<cfset styleCenter = wb.createCellStyle()/>
<cfset styleCenter.setAlignment(cellStyleStatic.ALIGN_CENTER)/>

<!---Dates--->
<cfset styleDate = wb.createCellStyle()/>
<cfset styleDate.setDataFormat(createObject("java","org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat").getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy"))/>

<!--- Text Wrapping--->
<cfset sheet1.FormatColumn(6, {textwrap="true"})/>

    <!---Sheet 1 (Numbers)--->
<!---Rows and columns--->
    <cfset row = sheet1.createRow(0)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(0,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(1,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(2,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(3,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(4,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(5,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(6,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(7,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(8,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(9,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(10,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(11,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(12,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(13,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(14,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(15,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(16,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(17,6000)/>
    <cfset sheet1.setColumnWidth(18,6000)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(0)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header1')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(1)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header2')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(2)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header3')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(3)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header4')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(4)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header5')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(5)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header6')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(6)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header7')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <!---<cfset cell = row.createCell(7)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header8')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>--->
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(7)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header9')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(8)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header10')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>  
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(9)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header11')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(10)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header12')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(11)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header13')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(12)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header14')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(13)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header15')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(14)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header16')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(15)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header17')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(16)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header18)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(17)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header19')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(18)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('Header20')/>
        <cfset cell.setCellStyle(styleTitle)/>  



<cfloop query="getall">

    <!--- Query Engineer Notes for this Tracking Number --->

    <cfquery name="Eng_Notes" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        SELECT Eng_Notes AS Note
        FROM tbl_ERD_Eng_NOTES
        WHERE ERD_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getAll.ID#" />
    </cfquery>

    <cfset variables.lstNotes = valueList(Eng_Notes.Note, " *** ") />

    <cfset row = sheet1.createRow(javacast("int",#getall.currentrow#))/>   
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(0)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info1#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(1)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info2#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(2)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info3#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(3)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info4#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(4)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info5#')/>   
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(5)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info6#')/>
              <cfset cell = row.createCell(6)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#variables.info7#')/>
    <!---<cfset cell = row.createCell(7)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info8#')/>--->
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(7)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info9#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(8)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info10#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(9)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info11#')/>   
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(10)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info12#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(11)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info13#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(12)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info14#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(13)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info13#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(14)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info14#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(15)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info15#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(16)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info16#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(17)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info17#')/>
    <cfset cell = row.createCell(18)/>
        <cfset cell.setCellValue('#getall.info18#')/>            
</cfloop>
```

I have tried to use the `SpreadsheetFormatCell`, [as posted here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6747.html), although I am aware that it would only text wrap 1 cell. All that accomplished is for my Excel page to display the HTTP 500 page.

I have also tried the `SpreadsheetFormatColumn` method, [as posted here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6806.html), and got a lot a errors.

Any help would be awesome, and if there is another post similar to this one please point me in that direction. There is always the possibility I missed it.

Comment: What did you try with SpreadsheetFormatColumn and what were the errors?

Answer (score 2):

Using ColdFusion 9, right?  It's frustrating because the ColdFusion 9 documentation states that it works, but it's horribly broken. I think this may have been fixed in the recent ColdFusion 11, but it still uses Apache POI libraries that are multiple versions old.

Try using spreadsheetWrite().  I've found that there are differences when saving using tag versus script:

http://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/65341875453/differences-saving-coldfusion-excel-data-w-tag-vs

NOTE: It'd be great if this type of testing could be done using CFLive.net or TryCF.com, but they don't allow for file generation for security reasons.

Comment: Silly question, but .. exactly what code are you guys using to wrap the text (and what version 9.x) ? Reason for asking is I do not see any code in the OP that would wrap cell text and in my brief tests "textwrap" worked with 9.0.1.

Comment: *It'd be great if this type of testing could be done using CFLive.net or TryCF.com* FWIW - You can. Instead of writing the sheet to a file, use `<cfcontent variable="...">` instead.

Comment: spreadsheetWrite() saves the spreadsheet object directly to the file system.  There's no way to capture that data (using cfcontent) in order to compare it with the output created by <cfspreadsheet action="write">.

Comment: Yes, I just realized you are talking about a different goal. I was saying he could use `cfcontent` to [test the formatting functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23479147/104223). If the goal is simply to compare the results of saving the spreadsheet to disk, then yes - it is not supported. BTW - Are you running 9.0.2? If so, what results did you get from the linked example? I am curious as it works fine w/CF9.0.1 + 10.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

> `<cfset sheet1.FormatColumn(6, {textwrap="true"})/>`

Without knowing more, my guess is that line causes an error. The variable `#sheet1#` is an instance of the POI class: [`org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html). That class does not contain a method named `FormatColumn(..)`, so it would definitely cause some sort of error. But again, is extremely difficult to troubleshoot errors without an actual error message or even a screen shot.

(If you do not have access to the necessary tools for some reason, I would suggest installing the CF Developer version locally (free). Then you will have full access to the CF Administrator, logs, etcetera and can configure the debug settings however you like.)

That said, I am not sure why you are using all that low level java code in the first place. Typically, you only *need* to dip into java if you are looking for some extra functionality that CF does not provide, or perhaps to work around a bug. Frankly, I am not yet convinced either one applies here ...  **Did you ever try the example below "as is"? It worked fine with 9.0.1. YMMV**

---

> I have tried to use the SpreadsheetFormatCell ... All that
>   accomplished is for my Excel page to display the HTTP 500 page.

Can you post the actual code you tried and the error message from the logs (and your full version)? There are definitely some bugs with spreadsheet functions in CF9, but a quick test of "textwrap" worked fine for me with CF9.0.1.

```
<cfset sheet = spreadSheetNew()>

<!--- enabled wrapping for single cell --->
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatCell(sheet, {textwrap="true"}, 2, 1)>

<!---
   enable wrapping for entire column
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatColumn(sheet, {textwrap="true"}, 2)>
--->

<!--- add text --->
<cfset SpreadSheetSetCellValue(sheet, "Short text", 1, 1)>
<cfset SpreadSheetSetCellValue(sheet, RepeatString("aaa ", 50), 2, 1)>
<cfset SpreadSheetSetCellValue(sheet, "More text", 3, 1)>
<cfset SpreadSheetSetCellValue(sheet, "Short text", 1, 2)>
<cfset SpreadSheetSetCellValue(sheet, "More text", 2, 2)>

<!--- resize column --->
<cfset SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(sheet, 1, 35)>

<!--- display results --->
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=test.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" 
          variable="#SpreadSheetReadBinary(sheet)#">
```

Comment: I must have been missing a comma the first time I tried it. I am now using this <cfset SpreadsheetFormatCell(sheet, {textwrap="true"}, 4,1)> and getting a HTTP 500. I am using CF 9.

Comment: Did you try the example above "as is" first? Verify it does what you need first, then work it into your code. As far as the error - server 500 error? Look in the CF logs to get the actual error message. Then update your question with the full error.

Comment: please excuse my ignorance, but how would I find the CF logs? I picked up ColdFusion like a week ago and have never used them.

Comment: They are usually located at `{cf_root}\logs`. For example, in windows: `c:\coldfusion9\logs`. There are several log files. This error is most likely in the `exception.log`. Keep in mind the location of the log directory can vary depending on where CF was installed. BTW, [Robust Exception Information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ff8) is typically enabled in Dev environments, so you can easily view error messages on screen, during development. Obviously it would be *disabled* on production.

Comment: Did you try the stand alone example above? What was the result? Side note - so as not to overlook the obvious, if you are using IE, be sure you turned of its [friendly error messages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807) or you will not see the server side error, even if robust exceptions are enabled in the CF Admin.

Comment: ColdFusion was downloaded while another coworker (who no longer works here) was using this computer, so I assume logs are saved all that stuff on his instance of the C drive since I do not have them, and I have no access to his files on the C drive. On the other hand after turning off friendly error messaging the error it was unable to download the excel because it could not find the site. When I don't use the SpreadsheetFormatCell it works fine aside from text wrapping.

Comment: Well like I mentioned, the above works as expected with CF9.0.1 and 10. So you are almost certainly doing something different. For one thing, you are using a lot of java code, which may not even be necessary .. Also, the code uses some methods that do not exist, which will cause errors (see my updated response for one issue). Again, I suggest installing the CF developer version locally, so you have access to debugging information. Also, start small. Test the example above "as is" first. Then go from there.

Comment: The above code does not text wrap for me either. The edit above does cause issues and I no longer have it in the code. That was just a test that I forgot to take out before putting the code on here. Thank you for the help though. I think i am just going to widen the columns more and just leave some buffer for mor information in the given cells. That is what the customer asked for originally. I just thought text wrapping would be better for them.

Comment: (Edit) Weird, as it works fine in 9.0.1 and 10 (use cflive.net or cftry.com). What is your full CF version? `<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion#">`. It is always possible they broke something, but just verify the results are not being cached. Maybe write the sheet to a file instead of using `cfcontent`, temporarily.